# Mongodb query actual time usage is different with explain result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, query-optimization

I have a mongodb query, when I run `explain('executionStats')`, the executionTimeMillis is 0.0, nReturned is 5. But when I run the whole query, it needs >2mins to get the result.

It's quite tricky, I made the tests below:

1. rebuilt index and run the query below:

```
db.Member.find({$or:[{number:{"$regex": /^2590000/}}]},{
    "createdAt": 1,
    "modifiedAt": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "number": 1,
    "familyName": 1,
    "givenName": 1,
    "displayName": 1,
    "startTime": 1,
    "endTime": 1,
    "state": 1,
    "deletedAt": 1,
    "preferredStore": 1,
    "gender": 1,
    "active": 1
}).sort({createdAt:-1, modifiedAt:-1})
```

It returned result in 200ms.

2. Then I ran this query, it's almost the same as first one, only regex is different:

```
db.Member.find({$or:[{number:{"$regex": /2590000$/}}]},{
    "createdAt": 1,
    "modifiedAt": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "number": 1,
    "familyName": 1,
    "givenName": 1,
    "displayName": 1,
    "startTime": 1,
    "endTime": 1,
    "state": 1,
    "deletedAt": 1,
    "preferredStore": 1,
    "gender": 1,
    "active": 1
}).sort({createdAt:-1, modifiedAt:-1})
```

It returned result in 2min.

3. I ran the first query again, now it needs 2min. But the explain result shows that the winning plan used correct index. executionTimeMillis is 0.0

Appreciate that anyone can help me on this. Thank you very much.

PS, there's the explain output:

```
{ 
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1.0, 
        "namespace" : "test.Member", 
        "indexFilterSet" : false, 
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "number" : {
                "$regex" : "^2590000"
            }
        }, 
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION", 
            "transformBy" : {
                "createdAt": 1.0,
                "modifiedAt": 1.0,
                "id": 1.0,
                "number": 1.0,
                "familyName": 1.0,
                "givenName": 1.0,
                "displayName": 1.0,
                "startTime": 1.0,
                "endTime": 1.0,
                "state": 1.0,
                "deletedAt": 1.0,
                "preferredStore": 1.0,
                "gender": 1.0,
                "active": 1.0
            }, 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT", 
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "createdAt" : -1.0, 
                    "modifiedAt" : -1.0
                }, 
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", 
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH", 
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "number" : 1.0, 
                                "createdAt" : -1.0, 
                                "modifiedAt" : -1.0
                            }, 
                            "indexName" : "number_createdAt_modifiedAt", 
                            "isMultiKey" : false, 
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "number" : [

                                ], 
                                "createdAt" : [

                                ], 
                                "modifiedAt" : [

                                ]
                            }, 
                            "isUnique" : false, 
                            "isSparse" : false, 
                            "isPartial" : false, 
                            "indexVersion" : 2.0, 
                            "direction" : "forward", 
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "number" : [
                                    "[\"2590000\", \"2590001\")", 
                                    "[/^2590000/, /^2590000/]"
                                ], 
                                "createdAt" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ], 
                                "modifiedAt" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "PROJECTION", 
                "transformBy" : {
                    "createdAt": 1.0,
                    "modifiedAt": 1.0,
                    "id": 1.0,
                    "number": 1.0,
                    "familyName": 1.0,
                    "givenName": 1.0,
                    "displayName": 1.0,
                    "startTime": 1.0,
                    "endTime": 1.0,
                    "state": 1.0,
                    "deletedAt": 1.0,
                    "preferredStore": 1.0,
                    "gender": 1.0,
                    "active": 1.0
                }, 
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT", 
                    "sortPattern" : {
                        "createdAt" : -1.0, 
                        "modifiedAt" : -1.0
                    }, 
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", 
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "FETCH", 
                            "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                    "number" : 1.0
                                }, 
                                "indexName" : "number", 
                                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                    "number" : [

                                    ]
                                }, 
                                "isUnique" : false, 
                                "isSparse" : false, 
                                "isPartial" : false, 
                                "indexVersion" : 2.0, 
                                "direction" : "forward", 
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                    "number" : [
                                        "[\"2590000\", \"2590001\")", 
                                        "[/^2590000/, /^2590000/]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "stage" : "PROJECTION", 
                "transformBy" : {
                    "createdAt": 1.0,
                    "modifiedAt": 1.0,
                    "id": 1.0,
                    "number": 1.0,
                    "familyName": 1.0,
                    "givenName": 1.0,
                    "displayName": 1.0,
                    "startTime": 1.0,
                    "endTime": 1.0,
                    "state": 1.0,
                    "deletedAt": 1.0,
                    "preferredStore": 1.0,
                    "gender": 1.0,
                    "active": 1.0
                }, 
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH", 
                    "filter" : {
                        "number" : {
                            "$regex" : "^2590000"
                        }
                    }, 
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "createdAt" : -1.0, 
                            "modifiedAt" : -1.0
                        }, 
                        "indexName" : "createdAt_modifiedAt", 
                        "isMultiKey" : false, 
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "createdAt" : [

                            ], 
                            "modifiedAt" : [

                            ]
                        }, 
                        "isUnique" : false, 
                        "isSparse" : false, 
                        "isPartial" : false, 
                        "indexVersion" : 2.0, 
                        "direction" : "forward", 
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "createdAt" : [
                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                            ], 
                            "modifiedAt" : [
                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true, 
        "nReturned" : 5.0, 
        "executionTimeMillis" : 1.0, 
        "totalKeysExamined" : 6.0, 
        "totalDocsExamined" : 5.0, 
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION", 
            "nReturned" : 5.0, 
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0, 
            "works" : 15.0, 
            "advanced" : 5.0, 
            "needTime" : 8.0, 
            "needYield" : 0.0, 
            "saveState" : 0.0, 
            "restoreState" : 0.0, 
            "isEOF" : 1.0, 
            "invalidates" : 0.0, 
            "transformBy" : {
                "createdAt" : 1.0, 
                "modifiedAt": 1.0,
                "id": 1.0,
                "number": 1.0,
                "familyName": 1.0,
                "givenName": 1.0,
                "displayName": 1.0,
                "startTime": 1.0,
                "endTime": 1.0,
                "state": 1.0,
                "deletedAt": 1.0,
                "preferredStore": 1.0,
                "gender": 1.0,
                "active": 1.0
            }, 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT", 
                "nReturned" : 5.0, 
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0, 
                "works" : 15.0, 
                "advanced" : 5.0, 
                "needTime" : 8.0, 
                "needYield" : 0.0, 
                "saveState" : 0.0, 
                "restoreState" : 0.0, 
                "isEOF" : 1.0, 
                "invalidates" : 0.0, 
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "createdAt" : -1.0, 
                    "modifiedAt" : -1.0
                }, 
                "memUsage" : 5404.0, 
                "memLimit" : 33554432.0, 
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", 
                    "nReturned" : 5.0, 
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0, 
                    "works" : 8.0, 
                    "advanced" : 5.0, 
                    "needTime" : 2.0, 
                    "needYield" : 0.0, 
                    "saveState" : 0.0, 
                    "restoreState" : 0.0, 
                    "isEOF" : 1.0, 
                    "invalidates" : 0.0, 
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH", 
                        "nReturned" : 5.0, 
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0, 
                        "works" : 7.0, 
                        "advanced" : 5.0, 
                        "needTime" : 1.0, 
                        "needYield" : 0.0, 
                        "saveState" : 0.0, 
                        "restoreState" : 0.0, 
                        "isEOF" : 1.0, 
                        "invalidates" : 0.0, 
                        "docsExamined" : 5.0, 
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0.0, 
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                            "nReturned" : 5.0, 
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0.0, 
                            "works" : 7.0, 
                            "advanced" : 5.0, 
                            "needTime" : 1.0, 
                            "needYield" : 0.0, 
                            "saveState" : 0.0, 
                            "restoreState" : 0.0, 
                            "isEOF" : 1.0, 
                            "invalidates" : 0.0, 
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "number" : 1.0, 
                                "createdAt" : -1.0, 
                                "modifiedAt" : -1.0
                            }, 
                            "indexName" : "number_createdAt_modifiedAt", 
                            "isMultiKey" : false, 
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "number" : [

                                ], 
                                "createdAt" : [

                                ], 
                                "modifiedAt" : [

                                ]
                            }, 
                            "isUnique" : false, 
                            "isSparse" : false, 
                            "isPartial" : false, 
                            "indexVersion" : 2.0, 
                            "direction" : "forward", 
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "number" : [
                                    "[\"2590000\", \"2590001\")", 
                                    "[/^2590000/, /^2590000/]"
                                ], 
                                "createdAt" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ], 
                                "modifiedAt" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }, 
                            "keysExamined" : 6.0, 
                            "seeks" : 2.0, 
                            "dupsTested" : 0.0, 
                            "dupsDropped" : 0.0, 
                            "seenInvalidated" : 0.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "ip-10-1-0-238.us-west-2.compute.internal", 
        "port" : 27017.0, 
        "version" : "3.6.16", 
        "gitVersion" : "204ab367a130a4fd2db1c54b02cd6a86e4e07f56"
    }, 
    "ok" : 1.0, 
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1624980989, 4), 
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1624980989, 4), 
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0, "15jqr8a7QTr1O05AMKkJ8g2dpII="), 
            "keyId" : 6941110485450227714
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the explain output?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `$or` operator in the _find_? Also, see [regex and index usage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use).

Comment: do you have compound index on `number, createdAt and modifiedAt`?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert I have added the output, thanks.

Comment: @sidgate yes I have, I used this command to create index: ```db.Member.createIndex({"number":1, "createdAt":-1,"modifiedAt":-1},{"name":"number_createdAt_modifiedAt","background": true})```

Comment: Whenever a query takes longer than 100ms, it should be logged.  When the first query takes 2 minutes, what is the plan summary in the log?